# How to get Application Name in sys.dm_exec_sessions

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008-r2

Execution of the `select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions` gives the `program_name` as **.NEtSQLClient Provider**. Instead I want the .Net application name to be returned. Is it possible to get (either sql query or front end code) the number of connections on a server open by a Application with its Application Name.

Comment: It's whatever the application has reported via the `Application Name` keyword in its [Connection String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx). If it doesn't specify one, all you can get is .NET SQL Client Provider. And it can easily lie if it wants to.

Comment: yes.. got the keyword.. Thanks..